# Setting a PGSQL Session Variable Value with SELECT Statement Output

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to set a session variable in a PG SQL statement with the value from a subquery SELECT statement.

The variable itself is to be an integer, the `loid` of a `large_object`.

```
SELECT set_config('my_special_var', (SELECT loid from PG_LARGEOBJECT LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1), false);
```

However I am getting the below error:

```
ERROR:  function set_config(unknown, oid, boolean) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT set_config('my_special_var', (SELECT loid from PG_LAR...
```

I have had a look at the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-admin.html) but there doesn't seem to be much information.

Is it not possible to do what I am trying or am I just missing something?

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 32-bit
```

Comment: Please try:  `SELECT set_config('my.special_var', (SELECT loid::text from PG_LARGEOBJECT LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1), false);`  If you do not use a `.` in the config variable name, then it wants to set an actual config variable.  The cast is because the signature is `set_config(text, text, boolean)`

Comment: That did it, thanks

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name noted, it's part of a security course, this version of Postgres is linked to an intentionally vulnerable application